# Training schedule till end of year

Tags: oracle, date, plsql

I have a schedule of my training, three times a week, for example -
MON, WED,FRI. I need to generate records for my schedule table with dates till the end of the current year when I have training.

The schedule table is:

```
CREATE TABLE trainingSchedule (
id NUMBER,
training_date DATE
);
```

If training date already exist - don’t insert a record.

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: I don't know from what to start? I mean, I can't start using any of function or procedure..no idea. May be you can advice any idea?

Comment: There is no a question; what is the problem?

Comment: Perhaps this would be easier to achieve using a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option. Read comments within code.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE trainingSchedule
  2    (id            NUMBER,
  3     training_date DATE
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> create sequence seq_tra;

Sequence created.

SQL> -- initial insert (just to show that MERGE will skip it
SQL> insert into trainingschedule values (seq_tra.nextval, date '2021-03-22');

1 row created.
```

`MERGE` will skip rows that are already inserted. I understood that you want to insert only dates that follow today's date; if that's not so, just remove the last condition.

```
SQL> merge into trainingschedule t
  2  using (-- this is a calendar for current year
  3         select trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy') + level - 1 datum
  4         from dual
  5         connect by level <= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy'), 12) - trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy')
  6        ) c
  7    on (c.datum = t.training_date)
  8    when not matched then insert (id, training_date) values (seq_tra.nextval, c.datum)
  9    -- insert only Mondays, Wednesdays and Fridays
 10    where to_char(c.datum, 'dy', 'nls_date_language = english') in ('mon', 'wed', 'fri')
 11    -- insert only dates that follow today's date ("till the end of the current year")
 12      and datum >= trunc(sysdate);

122 rows merged.

SQL>
```

What's in there?

```
SQL> select id,
  2    to_char(training_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy, dy', 'nls_date_language = english') tr_date
  3  from trainingschedule
  4  order by training_date;

        ID TR_DATE
---------- ------------------------
         1 22.03.2021, mon           --> see? No duplicates
       311 24.03.2021, wed
       309 26.03.2021, fri
       207 29.03.2021, mon
       354 31.03.2021, wed
       321 02.04.2021, fri
<skip>
```